# How to sum values in the same column based on other values in the same row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have three columns in an Excel spreadsheet: name, type and amount. (I have more, but the others aren't relevant to this problem). Each row contains the name of a playing card, its type and the number of copies included in the deck as such:

[image: Table example image]

In other cells outside this table, I have the total amount of cards. For example, the total amount of cards with the type "ranged".

```
=COUNTIF(D2:D70; "*ranged*")
```

What this shows me is only how many distinct cards there are with the type "ranged," but not how many cards with "ranged" would actually be included in the deck.

What I would like is a way to count the number of "ranged" cards. Meaning, the sum of the "amount" of all "ranged" cards.

In a for loop, this would be: If Type in row 2 = "ranged," add Amount in row 2 to the total, then repeat this operation for all rows.

I already did this with VBA, however, I have to update it manually. Also, I cannot have multiple different values in the "type" column, because x has to be 100% equal to the content of the cell in order to register it.

```
Sub Cardtypetotal()
 result = 0
 x = InputBox("SortBy", "Enter_Info")
  For i = 2 To 63
   If Cells(i, 3).value = x Then
    result = result + Cells(i, 5).value
   End If
  Next
 ActiveCell.value = result
End Sub
```

Is there a way to do this with excel formulas? Thank you.

I tried using:

```
=SUMIF(E2:E63; D2:D63 = "*ranged*")
```

But obviously, this counts nothing, as I need to compare individual cells, not arrays.

Comment: Did you try sumifs()?

Comment: I already tried using countif. I don't know how to make a universal formula that'd compare each row's "type" column and count the "amount" only if the type fit the criteria. If you know how to do so, please share it with me.

Comment: Per your own words, you need "the sum of the 'amount' for all 'ranged' cards" - that's *precisely* what `SUMIF`/`SUMIFS` does. *Did you try it?*

Comment: Sumif() would add the values of the cards as you specified in your question, not just count the number of cells. You can check out the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.sumif) and [this](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/use-wildcards-with-sumif-to-create-a-powerful-excel-function/) explains how to combine the function with wildcards

Comment: I'm voting to close as "unclear", since the title is about *multiplying*, the body is about *counting*, and the apparent requirement everybody understands is about *adding*. Please [edit] to clarify - also note, vertical=column, horizontal=row.

Comment: Added additional clarification at the end. I need to compare individual entries. How can I compare two arrays, with only the entries in the same row being compared?

Comment: @Daniel please don't use comments but [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52615858/how-to-multiply-values-in-the-same-column#) if you want to add more info. And please answer the people who asked you if you tried `SUMIF`.

Comment: I apologize, as I am very bad at asking questions in text form. But In the table example, If I wanted to count the number of "ranged" cards, the result should be 6, as I have 1 "Archgriffins," 3 "Barghests" and 2 "Bruxae" How can I achieve this with a formula, is what I am asking. Is it clear? I swear, this happenes every time I post on here.

Comment: Is it okay to reformat and repost this question? I don't know how spam rules work on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of your problems with the function could be solved by looking at the documentation of the `SUMIFS` function [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-values-based-on-multiple-conditions-e610ae0f-4d27-480c-9119-eb644f1e847e).

Your sumifs statement above is using the wrong syntax. You should be using commas, not semicolons, your equal sign sould also be a comma, and you should not use an asterisk infront of "ranged". Then your formula would work just fine.

If the above image showed Columns A, B and C, it would be someting like this

```
 =SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,"ranged")
```

Comment: Thanks! This seemingly works! I am using a different localization, so for me it's semicolons, not commas.

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem.  Whoever down voted this was clearly confused